# Minecraft Detect If A Mob Has NoAai Set To 1

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I would like to detect if a mob has NoAi set to 1 or 0. I searched but couldn't find anything. Can someone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can find that by simply running `data`.

NoAI is its own entry at the top level of an entity, so all you need is `data get entity <selector> NoAI` and it will return with its value.